# Converting a Joda DateTime to another timezone without changing the time

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I have tried all the ways in all the other questions on SO, and I can't get it to work. It is making me want to kill myself.

I have a set of times which are something like "04:00 AM AEST", except the AEST is a glitch, they should be GMT. What I want to do is change them to "04:00 GMT", and then convert them up to the correct AEST times (which in this example would be "14:00  AEST"). I have tried everything, and nothing works. The closest was to manually make a new DateTime using each individual value from the original date, e.g.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(origdate.year, origdate.month, origdate.day, origdate.hour, origdate.minute, origdate.second, timezone.GMT)
```

But for some reason the results came out four and a half minutes over, which is weird because timezones differ on hours and half hours.

Answer (score 0):

**1st Method** By following lines you will get GMT time in specified format :

```css
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
     Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
     DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyy HH:mm:ss z");   
     date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); 
     String gmtTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);
```

Hence, from GMT you can derive the time of any place.

**2nd Method** You can get system time of current place in milliseconds by:

```css
Long current_time = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```

Hope it helps.